# media queries : limit some css styles according to the screen size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

when I write some style in layout.css it applies in every screen size and in /* #Media Queries
 section, you have these sections:

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
```

so none of these do what I want.

Where should I write large screen specific css codes?

Comment: /************************************************************************************
smaller than 1280
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
your css here and choose what viewport you want
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you have a div like `<div claas="example"> </div>`

now write a css for `.example` which will be applied for those screen which are larger than range you mentioned in your media query

```
.example{
  /*..for larger screen style goes here....*/
 }
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) { 
  .example {
    /*...now give style for those screen which are less than 1400px...*/
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .example {
    /*...now give style for those screen which are less than 1300px...*/
  }
}
```

in the above you code you mention three different styles for

1. >1400px screen size
2. for 1300 to 1400px screen size
3. <1300px screen size

**EDIT::**

> "/* Larger than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */"

```
.example{
  /*..style for larger than 960px....*/
 }
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) { 
  .example {
    /*..style for lesser than or equal to 960 px...*/
  }
}
```

Comment: /* Larger than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {

}