# CSS Skeleton - how to position content at bottom of right column

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using Skeleton css boilerplate.  I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        some content here...
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        some bottomed content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the right (four columns) to be aligned to the bottom.

I have tried the following:

```
    ...
    <div class="four columns">
        <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
            some bottomed content here...
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

which works **until** the width of the screen is too narrow to fit the two columns side by side, where the right column appears below the left column, which is exactly what I want, except that when the `position:absolute;bottom:0;` is added, it aligns itself over the top of the bottom of column 1.

I have also tried adding a `top-margin` and a `padding-top` with no effect.

Any ideas as to how I can get this to work.

Comment: Found the answer to this in this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161815/limit-some-styles-with-skeleton-to-large-screens]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161815/limit-some-styles-with-skeleton-to-large-screens

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this?

```
<div class="twelve columns clear">
.clear { clear: both;}
```